# All the possible combination and permutations with repetition on python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, combinations, permutation

Essentially, I want to do

```
def get_all_possible(N)
    for i0 in range(N) :
        for i1 in range(N) :
            for i2 in range(N) :
             ... for iNm1 in range(N) : #Nm1 is N minus 1
                     yield [i0,i1,i2,i3,...,iNm1]
```

and make a list of all the possible combination of number `0-N` at each index and their permutations.
So when `N=4` then there should be `4^4` possible combinations to be output.
This nested for loop is not efficient, and the code is not easily expandable to general `N` case.

Comment: Any solution to this problem will run in O(n^n)

Comment: I know, but then for loop implementation of it is more than `n^n` due to the nature of python's for loop

Answer (score 2):

A solution that helps readability is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools
all_combs = list(itertools.product(range(4), repeat=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

try `itertools.permutations` or `itertools.combinations`

Comment: Thanks, I already tried those. but those things give you repeated permutations of all the possible combinations, which is overwhelming.